# Sum previous rows with query

Tags: sum, max

My first question here. :-) I have a Gsheet with transactions, these transactions are stored with id, date, buy/sell info and amount. I need to find the highest amount and the date with the highest amount for each ID. Generally this is not difficult, but I need to squeeze this whole formula into an array or query. One cell formula (one cell for date, one for cell for amount).

Look in my sample sheet. You see that the data is not sorted, and I need to change buy/sell to +/-. After that I run the sum function within an Arrayformula but only summarize when it's <= with row above.
By changing the id I'll get the date when the amount was at it highest.

Problem is that I do not have space to write the whole formula, date and max amount must be squeezed into it's cell.
Any suggestions?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xj9DfQFLAU4yaxiH80ceXCVQ04T4h35Mn2TOruOxX3Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need Unique() then Filter() with SORT() function.Currently I am writing from mobile so can't test right now.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking, I have an idea how to solve it.
But first, is this arrayformula possible to create with a query without using the Row() function?!

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(A2:AS20);"<="&ROW(A2:AS20);A2:AS20))
```